# Disable samba shares leaving alive wins support

Tags: linux, networking, samba, raspberry-pi, raspbian

On an embedded system (RPi, Raspbian Stretch) I use samba to share a directory with Windows systems. I also use the wins support to easily ssh into the system using the hostname instead of the ip address.

Sometimes, my application requires to stop samba service (so the shared folder is not reachable anymore) but I would like to keep alive the wins support.

Is it possible?

Here my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
netbios name = RPI
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
guest account = pi
wins support = yes

[RPi]
comment = rpi
path = /home/pi/resources
public = yes
writable = yes
available = yes
browsable = yes
```

right now I use `systemctl start/stop smbd.service` to enable or disable the samba service.

Comment: WINS is handled entirely by nmbd.service anyway, isn't it?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. I don't understand your hint...